# Only return value when row exists in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql query where I want to check if a certain post is has been liked already by the current user.

I do this currently by checking the existing likes for the post and whether one of them has the current user id as user id.

However, I have trouble doing this in a query. I am using PostgresSQL btw.

When I do the following:

```
CASE WHEN likes.user_id = 5 THEN 1 END AS "liked"
```

I am required to add `likes.user_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause which results in multiple results per post since it groups them by likes.

I also try to do it with a count wrapped around it but since I use Knex and express, the ints get converted to strings, which I don't want.

Is there something I'm not seeing or doing wrong?

The full query in PostgresSQL is:

```
select 
    posts.id, 
    posts.created_at, 
    posts.text, 
    posts.title,
    count(DISTINCT likes.id) as "likeCount",
    count(DISTINCT comments.id) as "commentCount",
    count(CASE WHEN likes.user_id = 5 THEN 1 END) AS "liked"
from updates
LEFT JOIN comments ON updates.id = comments.update_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON updates.id = likes.update_id
WHERE posts.user_id = 5
GROUP BY posts.id, likes.user_id
ORDER BY updates.created_at
```

The result I am now getting is (simplified):

```
╔════╤═══════════════════════════════╤═══════════════╤════════════╤═══════╗
║ id │ created_at                    │ comment_count │ like_count │ liked ║
╠════╪═══════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╪═══════╣
║ 40 │ 2017-09-21 11:53:11.064774+02 │ 1             │ 0          │ 0     ║
╟────┼───────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 40 │ 2017-09-21 11:53:11.064774+02 │ 1             │ 0          │ 0     ║
╟────┼───────────────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────┼───────╢
║ 40 │ 2017-09-21 11:53:11.064774+02 │ 1             │ 0          │ 1     ║
╚════╧═══════════════════════════════╧═══════════════╧════════════╧═══════╝
```

Comment: Add the dataset, expected output and actual query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried my best to provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN likes.user_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS liked
```

This gives you 1 if there is at least one like from user 5, else 0.

(And this should result in an integer. If your framework is in the way, you may be able to force this by `MAX(...)::integer AS liked`.)

Comment: That won't work sadly, it's the same outcome as with count. The 1 and 0 get converted to strings because of some weird quirk somewhere in Knex/Express.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reliable way to sort them you can use

```
CASE WHEN likes.user_id = 5 THEN 1 END AS "liked"
GROUP BY yourcondition
LIMIT 1
```

This will get only the first row returned, so if you have a way to ensure the record you want will be returned first it may work for you. Other than that it's hard to help you without more information.

Comment: He's using Postgresql. LIMIT is non-standard MySql-only.

Comment: that info wasn't in the post when I first answered